# Mocking global/module level variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I have a module that looks like this:

```
import psycopg2

client = vault_client(vault_url, vault_certs_path, credentials)
vault_data = client.read(vault_path)['data']


def do_thing
     connection = psycopg2.connect(
                dbname=vault_data['database'],
                host=vault_data['cluster_name'],
               ...
               )
```

How do I test this do_thing method. I need to mock out vault_data and the import of psycopy2. I need to ensure:

1. That the psycopg2.connect methods receives the right arguments
2. How do I mock the `vault_client` method to return a mock that then returns a dictionary when the `read` method is called on the mock?

I have this but the real methods get called:

```
    @mock.patch("sources.segment.handler")
    @mock.patch("sources.segment.handler.psycopg2")
    def test_attempts_to_connect_to_redshift(self, mock_psycopg2, mock_handler):
        mock_handler.vault_client.return_value = {
            "data": {
                "database": "some_database",
                "cluster_name": "some_cluster_name",
                "port": "some_port",
                "username": "some_username",
                "password": "some_password",
            }
        }
        do_thing()

        mock_psycopg2.connect.assert_called_with("some database")
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem here is that it's too late to mock something by the time the module with `do_thing()` has already been imported. You can try the following trick:

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

psycopg2_mock = MagicMock()
sys.modules['psycopg2'] = psycopg2_mock
import module_with_do_thing
del sys.modules['psycopg2']

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    def test_attempts_to_connect_to_redshift(self):
        ...
        assert psycopg2_mock.has_required_properties
```

Moving the `import module_with_do_thing` line to the actual test method with the right patch might work as well.

Comment: What about the vault client part? That part is also making a real api call on import. How do I stop that?

Comment: Same way, just overwrite one more module in `sys.modules`.

Comment: What's going on here? Were' setting the psycopg2 as a mock, importing the module, and then deleting the mock that we set?